# how to limit the space of a random location for a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I want to create a button "Skip Intro", similar to the one on Netflix (but with a ridiculous part where a button changes its location randomly as soon as you hover over it). The code for changing to a random location is already done. But I want to keep the location of the button only limited to the inside of a video frame. How can I do this?

```js
var button = document.querySelector(".button");

function randomizePosition() {
  var randomX = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
  var randomY = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;
  console.log("randomX", randomX, " : randomY", randomY)
  button.style.left = randomX + "px";
  button.style.top = randomY + "px";
}
randomizePosition();

button.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
  randomizePosition();
});
```

```css
.button {
  stroke: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  //border-radius: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: solid 3px darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class='button'>SKIP INTRO</div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g_4aEFYj3QA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
```

Here is a link to my work: https://codepen.io/artfsch/pen/ZEjZLgw

I know that it's possible in JS to limit the variable to a range and set it to be only randomized within a specific range. Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: would be way easier and smarter to not work with pixel (responsiveness reasons) but to place it absolutely to its relative parent container. Then you limit the button placement with a container that you can simply adjust with CSS. It also requires less computing resource as it not constantly has to read out the window height and width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to make the video full-screen, you can accomplish this by limiting the possible new locations for the button — basically creating artificial padding.

I've done this by centering your button on its top/left position:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

and creating a padding of 100px around your window

```
var randomX = (Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - 200)) + 100;
var randomY = (Math.random() * (window.innerHeight - 200)) + 100;
```

https://codepen.io/QuiteQuinn/pen/YzOZjgE

```js
var button = document.querySelector(".button");

function randomizePosition(){
  var randomX = (Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - 200)) + 100; // Adding a 100px padding 
  var randomY = (Math.random() * (window.innerHeight - 200)) + 100; // Adding a 100px padding 
  console.log("randomX", randomX, " : randomY", randomY)
  button.style.left = randomX + "px";
  button.style.top = randomY + "px";
}
randomizePosition();

button.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
  randomizePosition();
});
```

```css
body, html{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.button{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: solid 3px darkgrey;
  background: white;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /*   Centering your button on its top/left position */
}
iframe{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='button'>SKIP INTRO</div>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g_4aEFYj3QA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```js
var button = document.querySelector(".button");
var videoFrame = document.querySelector(".video-wrapper");

function randomizePosition(){
  var frameRect = videoFrame.getBoundingClientRect();
  var minX = frameRect.left;
  var maxX = frameRect.right - button.offsetWidth;
  var minY = frameRect.top;
  var maxY = frameRect.bottom - button.offsetHeight;
  var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxX - minX + 1) + minX);
  var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxY - minY + 1) + minY);
  button.style.left = randomX + "px";
  button.style.top = randomY + "px";
}

randomizePosition();

button.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
  randomizePosition();
});
```

```css
.button {
  stroke: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border:solid 3px darkgrey;
}

.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 560px;
  height: 315px;
}
```

```html
<div class='button'>SKIP INTRO</div>
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g_4aEFYj3QA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: code-only answers can be considered low-quality. Always add a sufficient explanation of how your answer would solve the issue and how it works. SO is not a code writing service but a Q & A platform that should have teaching value for others.